# Build Runtime License option missing in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sitecore

I am attempting to build a runtime license for a third party component for ASP.NET. The instructions are to place the "licenses.licx" file in the root folder of the site. The file is also embedded as a resource

However, the option to build the runtime license is not shown when I right click on the file.

There's also some confusion to what it is meant by the "root folder of the site" Is it the root folder of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is one vital step missing. I first have to open my solution as a web page, and move the license.licx to be in the same folder as the solution file.

Only when I open the solution as a web page, can I see files in the root folder inside the solution explorer. There I can right click on the license.licx file and see the option to build run-time license.

Comment: "Web Site", not "Web Page" :)